# Creation of JWS in implementation of PSUOAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, open-banking

I am implementing PSUOAuth2 for OpenBank Apigee - DevPortal (Drupal-8).
In creation of JSON Web Signature, few arguments are unclear to me.
(Check out [specification here](https://openbanking.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DZ/pages/68550784/Open+Banking+Security+Profile+-+Implementer+s+Draft+v1.1.1#OpenBankingSecurityProfile-Implementer'sDraftv1.1.1-JSONSecuritySuiteInformationv1.0)).
First is the private key, can I use any general private key or is there a specific private key to be used. (I checked in Apigee Interface, there is possibility to download a Public Key Certificate but no private key as they are never distributed).
Second in JOSE Header Object to be constructed there is a parameter called kid (described as ''certificate id" in specification).